How to protect against overvoltage when the sliding contact of the potentiometer breaks in circuits with LM2596-ADJ?
How to protect against overvoltage when the sliding contact of the potentiometer breaks in circuits with LM2596-ADJ? For example, in the circuit below at the link
CC/CC Buck Schematic (Circuit Help)

Please define what overvoltage means. Also, how would any circuit know what is normal and what is overvoltage due to sliding contact break?

How wide adjustment range do you need?

Output voltage adjustment in the range of 2-28 volts is required. A possible problem is when high voltage is thrown out when low voltage is required. In other circuits where the op-amp amplifies the difference between a fixed divided output voltage and a divided reference voltage which is divided using a potentiometer, it is enough to pull the output of the sliding contact of the potentiometer down with a resistor with a resistance much greater than the resistance of the potentiometer. Then, when the slider breaks, the feedback circuit will set a near-zero voltage at the output.

I don't think there is an easy way with that particular circuit, or others where voltage is proportional to rheostat resistance. There are less  easy ways, say using a dual pot.

Thank you. The double potentiometer squares the probability of a sliding contact breaking by an exaggerated 0.01X0.01 = 0.0001 if we make the assumption that the break of each is not connected with the break of the other.

If a wiper opens in a double pot, does the voltage double?

@D.A.S. If you just parallel them, yes. Because it's a rheostat. I was thinking of a tracking limit voltage, but that may not be all that easy.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You have a faulty pot, perhaps poor-quality metal film.
Lack of feedback, an open circuit, can cause the failure of your target load from massive overvoltage.

This is a design failure.

An expected intermittent open-circuit wiper should reduce the voltage.
The pot should feedback from the low side of the voltage divider, not to Vout.
Adding a large cap to the pot wiper with an RC time constant greater than the intermittent period of xx ms might help, but that would be a bandaid.


The pot was poor quality, lowest cost

It's time to replace the pot with a better-quality pot.
Industrial pots are sealed from dust ($), consumer ones are not.
You might extend the wiper life with an electronic lubricant compatible with film, carbon, plastic, wire-wound or hybrids.


The pot may be underrated for current

Many good-looking pots are only rated for 1/40 W or 1/20 W due to the thin conductive coating over the plastic film when the current through a low tap R burns out the film.


The pot is just a trimpot or not designed for frequent use (3 million turns)

pot reliability is important to external power supply control reliability
some brands that come to mind are Bourns, CTS, and Piher, which have some higher power ratings that may have the reliable performance you can afford, or Alps/Alpine.



It takes a lot of experience and skill to choose reliable components, designs and products, that may not be found in a random hand-sketched drawing.

Below is the LTspice sim of a switching regulator similar to the LM2596-ADJ.
A 1MΩ resistor has been added from the pot wiper output to the regulator output. It normally has negligible effect on the output voltage since its value is much higher than the pot resistance, but prevents the output from rising if the pot wiper opens.
Thus if the wiper opens, the FB pin is now connected to the output through the 1MΩ resistor, which then drops the output voltage to the value of the FB reference voltage (here 2.2V).
In the sim, switch S1 simulates the open wiper pot, and you can see that when it opens at 4ms (red trace), the output (green trace) drops from its nominal 5V to 2.2V.

